# CSS display: none not working on Samsung S5 mini

Tags: android, css, samsung-mobile, display, samsung-galaxy

My HTML (without actual filenames and link locations):

```
<table>
          <tr>
              <td class="tableLogo">
                  <a href="link">
                      <img src="img" />
                  </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <a href="link">Link</a>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

My CSS:

```
.tableLogo {
    display: none;
}
```

So, this works fine in Firefox, on iOS, etc.
However, it just won't work on my testing device Samsung S5 mini. The image keeps being displayed.
I tried this also:

```
.tableLogo {
    webkit-display: none;
}
```

Which is also not working. Main goal is to have a media query to hide the logo on small devices. I started out with this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .tableLogo {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

But it did not work on the Samsung device (On iOS it did..) So i tried to go without the media-query, which as already mentioned did not work also.

Any hints on what the problem could be here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was a browser-chache problem. After clearing the cache it works as intended.